# Does Svelte have Vue's keep-alive?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am new to Svelte, and started building a simple app on it. I am not sure if I understood the lifecycle of Svelte deeply, but it looks like there's no option to enable this from the doc nor is there any information on the web about any similar feature to "Keep alive" from Vue.

Comment: Not sure what you ask for ... what is "Keep alive"? Maybe tell us what you want to accomplish?

Comment: From the web search I found it looks like they describe it as: "<KeepAlive> is a built-in component that allows us to conditionally cache component instances when dynamically switching between multiple components." In short, you have a choice on Vue to switch between components without reloading them again. "tabs" may describe it much better. I am not sure if Svelte has this feature. Just a quick thought as I am from Vue, and that was what kept me from using another framework for a while.

Comment: I guess https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/6040 is a better way to discuss this further.

Answer (score 7):

Svelte does not have a built-in [KeepAlive](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/keep-alive.html) component. There was an [issue opened](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/6040) for it on GitHub, but it was closed since it's a major enough change to require an [RFC](https://github.com/sveltejs/rfcs/). However, you may find that issue discussion interesting for alternatives/workarounds to such a component.

The main alternatives in Svelte are:

- keep state outside of the component (e.g. in a [store](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store)) so that the component can be unmounted without losing state
- hide/show elements using CSS so that components aren't unmounted, but are hidden instead

Answer (score 0):

Svelte might face challenges implementing the keep-alive feature due to the absence of vnodes.

- Keep-alive differs from merely preserving state, as it involves reusing DOM elements (significant performance distinction).
- Keep-alive, by causing elements to disappear from the DOM tree, is distinct from simple CSS hiding (significant performance difference).